# Firebase Cloud Messaging send message to iid imported Apns token

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm writing an application which should send push notifications from the server to android and iOS devices. I try to use FCM for this purpose.
iOS application used APNS so I can obtain apns subscription tokens on server side. Then I try to [batch import](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#create_registration_tokens_for_apns_tokens) these tokens, I get back some kind of registration tokens with length of 174 symbols instead of usual 152 used in Firebase.
When I use IID method GET https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/{token}, it successfully returns information about given token, but when I try to send message directly using this  token by using HTTP v1 API POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{0}/messages:send method with target field `"token":"f5MpeWlqg0E:APA91bHGpRR3_ygt10....CdI3Rtsodf8XMIQNlflF23mQ"` and ios specific payload, I get an error:

```
{   
    "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError",
        "errorCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
      },
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "message.token",
            "description": "Invalid registration token"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]   
   } 
}
```

Then, if I try to send same message to the same token again, I get another error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError",
        "errorCode": "UNREGISTERED"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And IID method returs 404 too, meaning that Firebase removed my token from system. 
The question is why do I get "wrong" token from IID that I cannot address and how can I send direct notifications to iOS phones.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the problem was in iid settings: when I tried to retrieve FCM token from APNS token I set "sandbox" to false, but used sandbox certificate, so the token was invalid.